# How to access the class name of a React object in this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a react component render method that has some children components in this.props.children. How can I get the component (class) name of each child to differentiate between them?

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child){
    // how can I get the class name of a child or some other identifier
})
```

Comment: Could you provide some code examples presenting what you have in your code?

Comment: Added some code to original post

Comment: It's still unclear what you are trying to do. Do you want to differentiate between them to style them differently? Do you want to display different data based. If you need help you need to ask precise question.

Comment: The question is how can I get the class name of a child or some other identifier? The children will have different properties depending on what component class it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you want is `child._currentElement.type.displayName` but I would be careful about using internals like this, unless you want to double check they still function correctly in every upgrade. I don't think there is a public api for getting the name of a component.

Comment: The answer is outdated, use `child.type.name` to get the `function.name`

Answer (score 9):

***Warning: this will not work in production if using minification***

In ES6 every function has its name stored in property [`function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) so you can get Class name with

```
import React from 'react'

...

getNameOfChildrenClass() {
    const singleChild = React.children.only(this.props.children),
          childClass = child.type

    return childClass.name        
}
```

I'm using [`React.children`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children) utility

Comment: becarefull with this. when you build your project for production with npm run build, the `child.type.name` will not be the same!
for example: if your checking for the name props to be equal to something.
`if(child.type.name === 'componentName')` this will not work in production mode

Answer (score 0):

The same as @Vaclav, but if you are using redux connect you will get "Connect" as name which may cause problems. Here is my improved version:

```
let{ name, displayName=name } = child.type;
React.cloneElement(child, {
  ...
  key:displayName,
});
```