# ReactJS: How to add a className to a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a class name to a child component, preserving the original classes that may be set to the component.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

    class ClassExtender extends Component {
        getChildrenWithProps = () => {
            let addedClass = "my-new-css-class-name";

            return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => 
                React.cloneElement(child, { className: [child.className, addedClass] })
            );
        };

        render = () => {
            return this.getChildrenWithProps();
        };
    }

    export default ClassExtender;
```

I'm getting a wrong result when my component renders:

```
<div class=",my-new-css-class-name">Test</div>
```

That points to two possible problems:

1. The comma may indicate I need to change code to `React.cloneElement(child, { className: child.className + " " + addedClass });`. That is a easy step.
2. `child.className` is returning `null`. How can I retrieve the current classe(s) attached to the child component ?

Comment: try instead: child.className => child.props.className

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218814/how-to-access-the-class-name-of-a-react-object-in-this-props-children

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> child.className is returning null. How can I retrieve the current classe(s) attached to the child component ?

```
child.props.className
```

Comment: This is what worked: `React.cloneElement(child, { className: child.props.className + " " + addedClass });`