# How to get className on click with React and iframe?

Tags: reactjs

I want to get the className of anything that I clicked on inside the iframe.

```
const getClassName = (e) => {
  console.log(...)
}

<iframe src="somewikipediapage"/>
```

Comment: Only way to do it is bubble the click event to the top of the iframe document and pass the class name using window.message  API

Answer (score 0):

following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218814/how-to-access-the-class-name-of-a-react-object-in-this-props-children), you can use this function :

```
getNameOfChildrenClass() {
   const singleChild = React.children.only(this.props.children),
      childClass = child.type

   return childClass.name        
}
```